# Reference Request: tangent space defined via cotangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, definition

Wikipedia gives several ways of defining the tangent space, the first two of which I have most popularly seen in books. However, the [third one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_via_the_cotangent_space)---where $T_pM = (I/I^2)^*$ with $I=\mathcal C^\infty(M)$ functions which vanish on $p$---I have yet to see as the choice definition for the tangent space (rather than an equivalence).

Are there any good references which begin with this definition and proceed with results? I had a look through my references and could not find any. I understand from the link that this is useful for algebraic geometry so I will leave it open as to exactly what field it is from. I am moreso interested in how they develop it from this definition. Thanks!

I have found in another answer on stackexchange [these notes](http://montgomery.math.ucsc.edu/classes/mfds/lect3_06.pdf) which have been insightful but didn't provide a reference like the one I am looking for (Warner does it via derivations).

EDIT: I have answered with a few algebraic geometry books, though I would certainly appreciate more references, especially interested to see if there are any differential geometry books which decide to develop from this definition.

Comment: In algebraic geometry, a cotangent space is more natural object, as you don't have to take the dual. Also, it has a clear description in terms of differential forms.

Comment: As xyzzyz says, any textbook on algebraic geometry will have this definition.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my question and comments, this definition is more common in algebraic geometry so some references that I found in my library include:

- Joe Harris's book, *Algebraic Geometry: A first course*, pg. 174-5;
- Ravi Vakil's notes, *Foundations of Algebraic Geometry* (Dec. 29, 2015 draft), pg. 101;
- Qing Liu's book, *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*, pg. 126.